# SQL Sort a Column by Mixture of both Asc and Desc (Sort by Waves)

Tags: sql, sorting

So I have two Columns (Company, Type)

```
Company Type
Bell    Mobile
Rogers  Mobile
Fido    Mobile
Bell    Mobile
Bell    Home
Fido    Home
Rogers  Home
Bell    Home
Bell    Home
Rogers  Home
Fido    Home
Bell    Mobile
Bell    Mobile
Fido    Mobile
Rogers  Home
Bell    Home
Rogers  Home
```

I want it to look like

```
Bell    Home
Bell    Home
Bell    Home
Bell    Home
Bell    Mobile
Bell    Mobile
Bell    Mobile
Bell    Mobile
Fido    Mobile
Fido    Mobile
Fido    Home
Fido    Home
Rogers  Home
Rogers  Home
Rogers  Home
Rogers  Home
Rogers  Mobile
```

The first column is just a regular sort by ascending. The second column, is a mixture of both asc/desc. Notice how the first set of Company (Bell) is sorted asc, then when you get to the second company set (Fido) it is sorted desc. And then when you get to the third set it is back to asc and so on...

At the moment, I have no clues on how to sort this type. But I think I would need to create two new columns: (CompanySortOrder, Values at 1~3 respect to each company and then 1,2 for Type) Keep in mind that this is example, so hard coded not possible as I expect more companies and more type also I might even be needing to sort a third column by the same way or the normal way of sorting.

Edit: I also want to add that sorting the second column, Type, could also start by Desc and then Asc and so on

Comment: Strictly alternating? How do you know whether the second column should *start* to sort ascending or descending?

Comment: First the sorting by what column, by asc or desc or by sorting alternating (whether it starts or asc or desc) is dynamic

Comment: I have a two drop down lists (first list is what column am I sorting) and drop down list is (by asc or desc) and a third check box (this determines if the sort will be alternating and whether it starts with asc or desc, that's given by the selection of second drop down list). Also. its obvious that first column variable, you cannot sort by alternating. So users will be able to add on another sorting variable with respective conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MS SQL Server or any other dbms that supports partitioning functions like `DENSE_RANK()` you can accomplish this by partitioning the data into groups based on Company and the apply different ordering depending on whether the group % 2 = 0 (that is, if it's even or odd).

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
ORDER BY Company ASC,
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY) % 2) WHEN 1 THEN Type END ASC, 
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY) % 2) WHEN 0 THEN Type END DESC
```

There might be other, more efficient ways to accomplish this, but this is what came to mind first.

With a third column it might look like this (I wrapped the query in a CTE for clarity):

```
;WITH sorted AS (
    SELECT *, 
        Sort1 = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY) % 2,
        Sort2 = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COMPANY, Type) % 2 
    FROM YourTable
    )
SELECT * FROM sorted
ORDER BY Company ASC,
CASE Sort1 WHEN 1 THEN Type END ASC, 
CASE Sort1 WHEN 0 THEN Type END DESC,
CASE Sort2 WHEN 0 THEN Type END ASC, 
CASE Sort2 WHEN 1 THEN Type END DESC
```

Comment: Amazing, it works. I never though it can be that simple query. What if I were to introduce a third column, to which I also need to sort by alternatings

Comment: If you want to add a third column you should be able to add another level of partitioning. I'll update my answer.

Comment: like this: "SELECT [Company],[Type],[Function] FROM {Sheet1}
ORDER BY Company ASC,
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Company]) % 2) WHEN 1 THEN [Type] END ASC, 
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Company]) % 2) WHEN 0 THEN [Type] END DESC,
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Type]) % 2) WHEN 1 THEN [Function] END DESC, 
CASE (DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Type]) % 2) WHEN 0 THEN [Function] END ASC"

Comment: Something like that, yeah.